# C# Passing 'TYPE' as parameter and then Compare with 'is'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert the following code to a GENERIC function, by eliminating the need to hardcode my 'control comparison'. any way to achieve this?:)

```
    private Control getControlByAccessible(string accessDesc, string accessName, Control wrapper)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in wrapper.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            if (ctrl.AccessibleDescription == accessDesc && ctrl.AccessibleName == accessName)
                return ctrl;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This was my first attempt, wasn't yield any result so far.

```
    private Control getControlByAccessible(string accessDesc, string accessName, Control wrapper, Type aControlType)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in wrapper.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is aControlType)
            if (ctrl.AccessibleDescription == accessDesc && ctrl.AccessibleName == accessName)
                return ctrl;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @stay_hungry: Yeah, It doesn't passed the debug :)

Comment: ok.. Now you got the solution from @Jon Skeet
. all the best!

Comment: @stay_hungry: Yeah indeed from his great solution, thanks for the comment too! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Type.IsInstanceOfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx):

```
if (aControlType.IsInstanceOfType(ctrl))
```

However, I would personally make it a genuinely generic method with a type parameter if possible, then use LINQ's `OfType` method. I'd also probably make it an extension method:

```
// This would need to be in a top-level non-generic class
public static T GetControlByAccessible<T>(this Control wrapper,
    string description, string name) where T : Control
{
    return wrapper.Controls
                  .OfType<T>()
                  .FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccessibleDescription == description &&
                                       c.AccessibleName == name);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
TextBox tb = someContainer.GetControlByAccessible<TextBox>("name", "desc");
```

Comment: This is so Cool! Thanks bro, for the effort for guiding a newbie like me. :) I learned stuff today!